# Proving Riemann integrability for characteristic function of interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, supremum-and-infimum

I am working through *Measure, Integration and Real Analysis* by Sheldon Axler. I'm quite rusty with analysis and I've gotten stuck on this problem and would appreciate any help. Sorry if I made any obvious mistakes, analysis really isn't my strong suit.

Suppose $a \leq s < t \leq b$. Define $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ by

$$ f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    1& \text{if } s < x < t,\\
    0              & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $\int_a^bf = t -s$.

Here is the definition of Riemann integrable functions provided:

i) A bounded function on a closed bounded interval is called *Riemann integrable* if its lower Riemann integral equals its upper Riemann integral.

ii) If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ is Riemann integrable, then the *Riemann integral* $\int_a^bf$ is defined by

$\int_a^bf = L(f, [a,b]) = U(f, [a,b])$.

Finally, upper and lower Riemann integrals are defined as follows:

Suppose $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ is a bounded function. The lower Riemann integral $L(f, [a,b])$ and the upper Riemann integral $U(f, [a,b])$ of $f$ are defined by

$$L(f, [a,b]) = \sup_{P} L(f, P, [a,b])$$, where P is a partition of $[a,b]$.

and

$$U(f, [a,b]) = \inf_{P} U(f, P, [a,b])$$

where the supremum and infimum are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$.

Here's my attempt so far (again, sorry if I'm way off). If so, any guidance would be really appreciated as I'm very confused on how to solve this:

Let $P$ be the equally spaced partition $a=x_0, \dots, x_n=b$ of $[a,b]$ with

$$x_j - x_{j-1} = \frac{b-a}{n}$$

for each $j=1, \dots, n$. Then

$$\begin{align}
U(f, [a,b]) - L(f, [a,b]) &\leq U(f, P, [a,b]) - L(f, P, [a,b]) \\
&=\frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n\left( \sup_{[x_{j-1} - x_j]} f - \inf_{[x_{j-1} - x_j]} \right) \\
&\leq \frac{b-a}{n} \cdot t-s
\end{align}$$
where the RHS of the final inequality will approach 0 as $n$ approaches infinity (this is the part I'm really not sure about). This implies that $U(f, [a,b]) \leq L(f, [a,b])$.

By an earlier theorem in the book, we know that $L(f, [a,b]) \leq U(f, [a,b])$.

Therefore, we have that $f$ is Riemann integrable since $L(f, [a,b]) = U(f, [a,b])$..

That's what I have so far. Thanks for the help! Let me know if you need any more information or definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your estimate for $U(f, P, [a,b]) - L(f, P, [a,b])$ is not correct. It could be
\begin{align}
U(f, P, [a,b]) - L(f, P, [a,b]) &= \frac{b - a}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(\sup_{[x_{j - 1}, x_j]}f - \inf_{[x_{j - 1}, x_j]}f) \\
&\leq \frac{b - a}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(1 - 0) \\
&= b - a.
\end{align}
This estimate is too crude.

For proving Riemann integrability of $f$, it is useful to use the following result: A bounded function $g \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that $U(g, P) - L(g, P) \leq \varepsilon$.

Given $\varepsilon$, the general strategy to find $P$ such that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) \leq \varepsilon$ is to choose $P$ so that the portions of $[a, b]$ where $f$ is badly behaved (i.e. discontinuous) are squeezed in intervals of total length arbitrary small, e.g. $\leq K\varepsilon^p$ for some $K, p > 0$.